# Pricing "Customizable Options" Stuck on Fixed Pricing - Percent

Tags: custom-options, pricing

I have installed a bitnami build of Magento 2 on AWS and have noticed that on their core build 2.1.2.0 we can't add a percentage based "Customizable Option" to any products. We can add the customizable option as a percentage in the backend but it shows as fixed in the frontend. Has anyone experienced this issue and has a fix please?

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create or edit a new product with mandatory product description and price, stock etc
2. Select 'Customizable Options' tab
3. Add Option title > Anything
4. Select Option type > Field
5. Add Price > enter 50
6. Select Price type = Percent
7. Add Sku = xyz
8. Save Product

**Expected result**

1. Open newly created product in frontend
2. Select Customizable Option from above
3. Test percentage increase

**Actual result**

fixed priced option only available - no percentage increase available. It's basically taken the % increase value and kept it as a fixed price increase. I did notice in the backend that when I change the option from `fixed` to `percent` that the $ value in the input box doesn't change to %.